# Generate random numbers except certain values

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I want to generate random numbers, but don't want them to be from `exclude` array. Here is my code.

```
public int generateRandom(int start, int end, ArrayList<Integer> exclude) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int range = end - start +1 - exclude.size();
    int random = rand.nextInt(range) + 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < exclude.size(); i++) {
        if(exclude.get(i) > random) {
            return random;
        }
      random++;
    }

    return random;
}
```

I use this function in a while loop, and during each iteration I add a new value to `exclude`.
Sometimes it returns numbers that belong to `exclude`. What's the problem?

Comment: Are `excludeRows` and `exclude` the same thing?

Comment: yes, I forgot to change the name

Comment: In this function you don't add numbers to `excludeRows`. So in my solution I don't do that, either. Should I supplement it?

Comment: Renamed all `excludeRows` to `exclude`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(!exclude.contains(random))
    return random;
```

Try this every time it will return the value that is not in exclude.

Comment: @user2081119 I suggest you to take a look at my solution. There are some remarks which would be helpful I think.

Answer (score 8):

I think there are some mistakes.

1) Range should be end - start + 1, because this is the range wanted.
2) If you really want random numbers (as "random" as possible on computers) then you shouldn't just get the next available number. Because in this case your random number will bear the characteristics of excluded numbers density/frequency.

```
public int generateRandom(int start, int end, ArrayList<Integer> excludeRows) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int range = end - start + 1;
    int random;

    boolean success = false;
    while(!success) {
        random = rand.nextInt(range) + 1;
        for(Integer i: excludeRows) {
            if(i == random) {
                break;
            } else if (i > random) {
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return random;
}
```

**UPDATE**

With Achintya Jha's answer my code could be improved (but note there are some remarks as well):

```
public int generateRandom(int start, int end, ArrayList<Integer> excludeRows) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int range = end - start + 1;

    int random = rand.nextInt(range) + 1;
    while(excludeRows.contains(random)) {
        random = rand.nextInt(range) + 1;
    }

    return random;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You check:

```
for(int i = 0; i < exclude.size(); i++) {
    if(exclude.get(i) > random) {
        return random;
    }
```

and if only the first is larger, you'll return the value.
Are you sure `exclude` is sorted?

You can use `if(exclude.contains(random ))` or the following algorithm:

if `(end-start)` is a reasonable number, and you need almost all values you can create a list of all acceptable numbers and use random on this list size and choose the random value as an index. then remove the unwanted number from the list and get another random index.

Comment: I believe he relies on the fact that exclude is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
    public int randomInt(int start, int end, int... exception) {
        int result = -1;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int range = end - start + 1;
        boolean equals = true;

        while(equals) {
            result = rand.nextInt(range);
            boolean differentOfAll = true;
            for(int i : exception) {
                if(result==i) {
                    differentOfAll = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(differentOfAll) {
                equals = false;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, we do not need to use `contains(random)` with a while loop.

To simplify the question, let's see what happens if we only have one excluding value. We can split the result to `2` parts. Then the number of possible values is `range-1`. If the random number is less than the excluded value, just return it. Otherwise, we could add `1`.

For multiple excluding values, We can split the result set into `size+1` parts, where `size` means the number of excluding values. Then the number of possible values is `range-size`. Then we sort excluding values in ascending order. If random number is less than the excluding value minus `i`, then we just return the random number add `i`, where `i` is the index of the the excluding value.

```
public int generateRandomNumberWithExcepts(int start, int end, List<Integer> excepts) {
    int size = excepts.size();
    int range = end - start + 1 - size;
    int randNum = random.nextInt(range) + start;
    excepts.sort(null); // sort excluding values in ascending order
    int i=0;
    for(int except : excepts) {
        if(randNum < except-i){
            return randNum + i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return randNum + i;
}
```