# Fast way to generate random columns elements

Tags: java, algorithm, actionscript-3, random

I have a simple problem and I need a fast way to achieve that. 
Suppose I have two columns like

```
1 6 
3 5
5 3
```

As you see, element 3, and 5 are there in the 2nd column, I would like to generate a new random elements in column one, such that there will be no elements in the 2nd column matched. The elements can be from 1 ->12

My approach : I have added all the elements in the 2nd column to a hash set, then I search for the elements in column one, and check if they are in the hash set, if that's true, try to generate a new random element.

I have another idea is to visualize the problem as a 1D array, remove the duplicates,..etc., but I don't want to modify any elements in the 2nd Array.

Comment: Why does your approach fail when the second column has duplicate numbers?

Comment: So you want data in column 1 never to appear in column 2?

Comment: what about if you get  duplicates in col1. Any issues?

Comment: because you need again to have another loop to check if the chosen random number is again in the set or no, and that's add more to the overall complexity

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935997/generate-random-numbers-except-certain-values

Comment: @Trying no problem, but it would better to not have all the first columns duplicated elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a rather straight forward solution

```
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }));

    Integer[] colOne = new Integer[] { 6, 5, 3 };
    numbers.removeAll(Arrays.asList(colOne));

    int notFoundInColOne = numbers.get(r.nextInt(numbers.size()));
```

Essentially we create our range, remove the elements in the range that are also in the column, then pick a random element from what remains of our range.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the `column2` values to `HashSet`.
2. Just use `(Math.random() * 12)+1` which will generate number form 1 to 12.
3. Now search whether the number generated is present in `set` if present in `set` than regenerate  i.e. go to step 2, else done.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

**`O(1)`**

I am taking just a a small sample i.e. 5

1. first create an array which contains 1 to 5 than `a [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
2. Now try to generate a random number from 1 to 5 (here you are generating an index of the array) , lets suppose it generates 2 than replace last element to 2 . So now the array will be a[] = {1, 5, 3, 4} and decrement the index value.
3. now you will have to generate a random number from 1 to 4. Lets suppose 3 than swap 3 and last value. So array is {1, 5, 4}. Decrement the index i.e. now 3.

Comment: for the second approach, how are you making sure that there is on duplicated element in the 2nd columns ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh above code always generates unique number from 1 to 5. No repetition at all.

Comment: they should be unique, but not to themselves, to the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will work for you: For each number from 1 to 12, if the number is not in column 2 then add it to a list.  While column 1 is not filled, randomly choose an item from the list and remove it, then add it to column 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps:
1. Create an array. 
2. Fill it with minimum value to maximum value. 
3. Suffle the array. Read array sequentially.

Use Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm for suffle