# How do i restrict a Java random number generation

Tags: java, random

Here is the deal: I have a java code that generates a random number between two numbers and it works just fine. But i'm trying to achieve something. I want it in such a way that after the first number has been generated, when it recalls it, it doesn't generate that same number. For instance, if number 4 is generated, i want it now to be included among the possible generated numbers for the second time. To make things a little bit clear, here's my code.

```
      int Maximum=10;
      int Minimum=1;
      int r;
      r = (int)(Math.random() * Maximum) + Minimum;
```

is there anything i can do to make the code above not to generate a particular number between 1 and 10? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935997/generate-random-numbers-except-certain-values

Comment: hold random number in a temporary variable and use an if check. if the next random number is same as the previous one, skip it.

Comment: It looks like you're not generating random numbers, but drawing elements from a set without replacement.

Comment: LinkedHashSet would guarantee, that you have no duplicates in your generated sequence, and keep the original order of generation.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If you're putting restrictions on a PRNG, it's not exactly going to be random anymore, is it? In fact the outcome is going to be incrementally more predictable.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke it's one of the most common questions about random numbers on this site - confusion between generating random numbers and randomly drawing elements from a range without replacement...

Answer (score 2):

You could fill a collection and simply removed a randomly selected number:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = /* start */; i < /* end */; i++) {
    nums.add(i);
}

//Elsewhere
Random rand = new Random();
int get = nums.remove(rand.nextInt(/* end */);
/* end */--;
```

This may be a bit slower initially for large amounts of numbers but the end result is a lower time-complexity on your checks for new numbers (whereas a while loop could in theory be `O(∞n)` if I'm not mistaken)

Alternatively, use `Collections#shuffle`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like random number generation, it seems like randomly shuffling a `Collection`.

In Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int min = 0;
    final int max = 10;
    final List<Integer> nums = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).
            boxed().
            collect(toList());
    Collections.shuffle(nums);
    nums.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
3
10
5
0
8
7
9
2
1
4
6
```

Each number `[0, 10]` appears only once in a random order.

Comment: `nums.forEach(System.out::println)` god I love Java 8

Comment: Solution is restricted to Java8, and also way too complicated for a budding programmer to understand (evident from the question asked).

Comment: @Andrew you're entitled to your opinion. Don't really see where the complexity comes in.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to exclude a single number replace this:

```
r = (int)(Math.random() * Maximum) + Minimum;
```

with this:

```
while( ( r = (int)(Math.random() * Maximum) + Minimum) == excludedNumber );
```

Comment: Pls, does excludedNumber need to be initialized?

Comment: This answer would not work unless you were excluding one (and *only* one) number. That, and it can have an infinite time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int Maximum=10;
    int Minimum=1;
    int r;
    int[] intArray = new int[6];


    for(int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++){

        r = (int)( Minimum+ (Math.random()* (Maximum-Minimum+1)) );

        if(!intList.contains(r)){
            intList.add(r);
            intArray[i]=r;
            System.out.println(r);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(r+ "is a duplicate generated earlier, not putting in array again");
            i--;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `List` has `O(n)` contains. Also this is very inefficient way of achieving a very simple goal. In theory it might need to generate _infinity_ numbers to get one that hasn't been seen before. In practice, as we get towards the end of the range search time will increase.